# Check for several type inside when statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, typechecking, kotlin-when

Let's say I've the following:

```
sealed class Color(val name: String) {
    object Red : Color("red")
    object Green : Color("green")
    object Blue : Color("blue")
    object Pink : Color("pink")
    object Yellow : Color("yellow")
}
```

Is it possible to check if a color is a primary one using a when statement i.e.:

```
when(color) {
    is Red, Green, Blue -> // primary color work
    is Pink -> // pink color work
    is Yellow -> // yellow color work
}
```

Comment: `is Red, is Green, is Blue -> ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. According to the grammar of [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when)

```
when
  : "when" ("(" expression ")")? "{"
        whenEntry*
    "}"
  ;
whenEntry
  : whenCondition{","} "->" controlStructureBody SEMI
  : "else" "->" controlStructureBody SEMI
  ;
whenCondition
  : expression
  : ("in" | "!in") expression
  : ("is" | "!is") type
  ;
```

the `{","}` means the element can be repeated more times separated by commas. Note however that you have to repeat `is` too and smartcasts wont work if you do with different unrelated types.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can do it slightly more concisely by omitting the `is` entirely:

```
when (color) {
    Red, Green, Blue -> // ...
    Pink -> // ...
    Yellow -> // ... 
}
```

This is checking the *values* for equality, unlike the `is` code which is checking the *types*.  (Red, Green, &c are objects as well as types, which is why both work.  I suspect that this way may be fractionally more efficient, too.)

Comment: It just occurred to me that what the OP wrote might even work... it will check for the type for `Red` and the value for `Green` and `Blue`. I assumed that the OP had already tried their suggested solution but they probably didn't (luckily, so now we all have a little bit clearer the possible choices). Thanks for the additional insights.